# Bootstrap fixed sidebar causes main content to overlap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am a novice when it comes to Bootstrap and css in general. I would like a site with a fixed sidebar, fixed top nav and main content that scrolls.

The navbar is fixed and works ok. The layout of the sidebar and main content is fine too. The problem comes when I set the sidebar to fixed. The main content overlaps the sidebar.

I am using a basic grid layout:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-3 affix">
       sidebar is here
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
        main content
    </div>
</div>
```

I have tried adding a margin to the left of the main content to push it over but it looks horrible when resized to smaller device.

What is the correct way to achieve a fixed sidebar whilst still maintaining responsiveness?

Answer (score 0):

As I know, you should add `affix` to div inside `col-md-3` like

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3"> 
        <div id="myAffix" class="list-group" style="width:150px;">
            <a href="#section1" class="list-group-item">Section1</a>
            <a href="#section2" class="list-group-item">Section1</a>
            <a href="#section3" class="list-group-item">Section1</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-9">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using col-md-3 (and col-md-9) have you tried using col-xs-3 (and col-xs-9)?

Answer (score 0):

Right boys i've resolved this little bad boy for you I'll give you an example of my markup

Lets say we have two elements

```
<div class="sidenav col-sm-3"></div>
<div class="main-content col-sm-9"></div>
```

For those who assumed adding affixed so the sidenav / sidebar element forget it, this just makes things a pain in the backside. You don't need to use the affixed plugin and certainly don't go a long the lines of what I was thinking and write a jquery plugin to toggle the sidenav element class.

The solution is simple and it just revolves around media queries and a very minor css change (i know right). In my example I want my sidenav element to not scroll on anything higher than a mobile screen, so simple solution is add these two media queries.

```
/* On small screens, set height to 'auto' for sidenav and grid
================================================================================= */
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .sidenav {

    height: auto;
    padding: 15px;
  }
  div.sidenav.col-sm-3{
        position:static;

  } 

}

/* On Larger Screens
================================================================================= */

    @media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

        div.sidenav.col-sm-3{
            position:fixed;

        } 

    }
```

In a nutshell I have simply added two media queries to solve the problem. We were all thinking way too complicated. Well any of us having not attempted this previously.

The first query I added was to tell all larger screened devices that I wanted to FIX the position of my sidenav element to the left and prevent it from scrolling. I achieved this by adding the position attribute to the query with the 'fixed' value.

The second query simply resets this attribute value for mobile devices to 'static'. For any who don't know the default of any positioned element is static.

Check the code and just play around with screen sizes as you feel fit but it's working for me. Enjoy your weekend lads. Digital hi-5

FYI IF this doesn't work for you then chances are you experienced what I did first time around and qualify your css a little more. For example don't just style as .classname{position:fixed;} instead use specificity rulings and something like firefoxes firebug tool. click on the element (if you need too) and fully qualify as much as needed your css so for example

instead of this .sidenav{position:fixed}
do this div.sidenav.col-sm-3{position:fixed}

In your example you may need to specify a little more or less, everyones markup will differ :)